# How to model HashMap/Dictionary in the ProtoBuf efficiently

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a protobuf file serialized by .NET code and I would like to consume it into Java. In the .NET code, there is Dictionary data type and the proto schema looks like

```
message Pair {
   optional string key = 1;
   optional string value = 2;
}

message Dictionary {
   repeated Pair pairs = 1;
}
```

Just as described in stackoverflow post 
[Dictionary in protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194845/dictionary-in-protocol-buffers).

I can use protoc to compile the proto file into Java classes fine. I can deserialize the protobuf file into Java objects successfully. The only problem is that it translates to a **List** of Pair objects in Java instead of **HashMap**. Of course, I still have all the data, but **I cannot access the data as efficiently as I prefer**. If I have the value of the key, I have to loop through the whole list to get its corresponding value. This does not seem to be optimal.

I am wondering if there is a better way to model Dictionary/Map data type in the protobuf.

Thanks

**Update:**

I tried Jon Skeet's suggestion to add map type field in the addressbook example and still ran into issue.

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;        // Unique ID number for this person.
  optional string email = 3;
  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }
  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
  }
  repeated PhoneNumber phone = 4;
  map<string, string> mapdata = 5;
}
```

The protoc throws error when compiling

```
addressbook.proto:25:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
addressbook.proto:25:6: Expected field name.
```

According to Google protobuf doc, proto 2 does support map type https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps . As I quote,

> Maps cannot be repeated, optional, or required.

So I don't really know why protoc cannot compile it. There is another discussion here [have to create java pojo for the existing proto includes Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407123/have-to-create-java-pojo-for-the-existing-proto-includes-map). The answer suggests that map is only a proto 3 feature. This contradicts google's documentation.

Comment: If you are using proto3, you can use a Map. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3?hl=en#maps

Comment: @AndyTurner: Maps are supported in proto2 as well. They were introduced at the same time as proto3, but you don't have to be using a proto3-syntax file to use them.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, [maps are already supported in "protobuf proper" as of v3.0](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#maps). For example, your proto is effectively:

```
message Dictionary {
    map<string, string> pairs = 1;
}
```

The good news is that with the key and value fields you've defined, that's fully backward-compatible with your existing data :)

The bad news is that I don't know whether or not protobuf-net supports it. If you're not actually using the `.proto` file on the .NET side, and doing everything declaratively, you may just be able to modify your `.proto` file, regenerate the Java code, and go...

The remaining bad news is that maps were introduced in v3.0 which is still in alpha/beta at the time of this writing. Now, depending on when you need to ship, you may decide to bet on v3.0 being released by the time you need it - the benefits of having nice map syntax are pretty significant, in my view. Most of the changes being made at the moment are around the new proto3 features - whereas maps are allowed within proto2 syntax files too... it's just that you need the v3.0 compiler and runtime to use them.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Yes, I don't think protobuf-net supports it. If there is a dictionary type, it generates the repeated key-value pair type, instead of map. As you guessed, the protobuf was defined declaritively in .NET side as annoatation.  We have to use protobuf-net to generate to .proto file from code and make modification manually (a lot). I will verify the backward compatibility part and report back.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, adding a map field in the addressbook example. But the protoc throws error addressbook.proto:31:5: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated". 
addressbook.proto:31:8: Expected field name. My protoc version is 2.6.1.  Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407123/have-to-create-java-pojo-for-the-existing-proto-includes-map and it reports the same issue.

Comment: @Lan: You'll need a more recent version of protoc. Will edit to clarify that.

Comment: I reached the same conclusion after reading some post on the mailinglist. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/p4WxcplrlA4. After download the protobuf  3 alpha 3, I can get the map working. And it does seem to be backward compatible. Thanks for the help